# Concatenate String to End of File Object

Tags: java, file, concatenation

I have an object of class File that represent a directory. I now want to create a new File object that refers to a file within that directory. The following code seems to work:

```
String filePath = myDirectory.getAbsoutePath().concat("\\myFileName");
File theFile = File(filePath);
```

But, I was wondering if there was a way to do it without the File --> String --> File conversion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the constructor `public File(File parent,  String child)`

like `File newFile = new File(myDirectory, "myFileName");`

See for example:
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.io/File/Java_File_File_parent_String_child_Constructor.htm

Comment: That was easy. Thanks.